# How to remove list of faces and it's vertices from a mesh

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, geometry, mesh

I am trying to remove a list of faces as well as their respective vertices (if they are no longer referenced) from a mesh, but so far I have only been able to successfully remove the list of faces. The idea is that for each index that is removed all indices which are larger than the one removed should be decremented by 1.

The mesh is represented simply by a list of vertices and a list of indices (and optionally a list of triangles).

Currently the code to remove just triangles does this:

```
    private IMesh DeleteTriangles(IMesh input, IEnumerable<int> indices_to_delete)
    {
        var triangles_to_delete = new HashSet<int>(indices_to_delete);

        _triangles_to_keep = _mesh.Triangles.Where((t, count) =>
            !triangles_to_delete.Contains(t.A) &&
            !triangles_to_delete.Contains(t.B) &&
            !triangles_to_delete.Contains(t.C)).ToList();

       // return new mesh
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with in the end:

```
    public IMesh DeleteVertices(IMesh mesh, IImmutableList<int> indices_to_remove)
    {
        var indices_to_remove_set = new HashSet<int>(indices_to_remove);
        var new_vertices = new List<Vector>();
        var map = new int[mesh.Vertices.Count];

        for (var i = 0; i < mesh.Vertices.Count; i++)
        {
            if (indices_to_remove_set.Contains(i))
            {
                map[i] = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                new_vertices.Add(mesh.Vertices[i]);
                map[i] = new_vertices.Count - 1;
            }
        }

        var new_triangle_list = from triangle in mesh.Triangles
                                where map[triangle.A] != -1 &&
                                      map[triangle.B] != -1 &&
                                      map[triangle.C] != -1
                                select new IndexTriangle(
                                    map[triangle.A],
                                    map[triangle.B],
                                    map[triangle.C]);

        //build new mesh...
    }
```